# Another question flagged for migration here

Tags: discussion, migration

[This question on Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/113085/why-do-chrome-and-adobe-use-download-wizards-to-install-software) on installers has been flagged for possible migration here.

I'm not convinced myself, so I thought I'd get a second opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. I wouldn't migrate it. The OP doesn't seem to be asking whether download managers improve the experience, but rather why such a compromise is necessary.

Comment: It looks like the answers they're getting are quite applicable and helpful, it could have been asked here but it seems like they're getting the answers they need.